# Chrome extension get element.data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

i have problem, because i cannot get element.data. Its always undefined, when i try to use it in extension, but when i paste the same code in console on youtube (developer mode) its working, In manifest version 2 i inject this code in content script but in version 3 its inpossible.

First:    `console.log(el)` => works
Second:    `console.log(el.data)` => undefined

Manifest version 3
service_worker

```
function injectFc() {
  document.querySelectorAll('yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer:not([profile-link])').forEach(el => {
    console.log(el)
    console.log(el.data)
  })
}

setInterval(() => {
   let queryOptions = { active: true, currentWindow: true };
  chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions, (tb) => {
    var actTid = tb[0]
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: {tabId: actTid.id, allFrames: true},
      func: injectFc,
    },
    () => {
        console.log(123);
    };
   });
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Add `world: 'MAIN'` to executeScript parameters.

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome extension manifest v3 you still use the content script. The content script allows you to set it to a specific domain, such as *[www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)*. Please check you are using the correct matches.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Inject Code",
  "action": {},
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Inject the code from content script",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["main.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://www.youtube.com"]
}
```

**main.js**

```
console.log("start the script");

function injectFc() {
  console.log("run injectFc");
  document.querySelectorAll('yt-live-chat-text-message-renderer:not([profile-link])').forEach(el => {
    console.log(el);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(el.data));
  })
}

window.setInterval(function () { injectFc(); }, 20000);
```

To collect the Live stream messages please check the [official Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages).